# Expect script to install Vagrant - terminating for no apparent reason

Tags: macos, vagrant, expect

I am running a simple expect script that uses curl to pull the vagrant dmg, attaches it, installs it and proves password and then detaches.

Individually all the commands execute at the command line and the install works.
However when executing inside of the script it terminates after the curl completes.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 60

exec curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.2/vagrant_2.2.2_x86_64.dmg
exec hdiutil attach vagrant_2.2.2_x86_64.dmg
spawn sudo  installer -package /Volumes/Vagrant/vagrant.pkg -target /
expect "*?assword" { send “password” }

spawn hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Vagrant
```

The output I get is (concatenated):

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  1 31.2M    1  563k    0     0  2218k      0  0:00:14 --:--:--   0:00:01 8873k
 97 31.2M   97 30.5M    0     0  9628k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 9627k
100 31.2M  100 31.2M    0     0  9668k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 9667k
    while executing
"exec curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.2/vagrant_2.2.2_x86_64.dmg"
    (file "./vag" line 9)
```

At which time the script terminates.

Comment: does it terminate after 60 seconds? Also, what is the exit status of `curl`? You may need to `catch` the exec command: see the [`exec` page in the Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec#1a39e854c66866d4b4567dcb8126b8f0914bdab191eea3a4812f3ca8d9d2bff3)

Comment: it executes immediately - does not time out.
Are there hidden errors, I thought all errors were sent to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tcl's [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) would fail if the executed command outputs anything to stderr.
2. `curl` outputs the download progress info to stderr .

So you need to ask `exec` to ignore the output to stderr: `exec -ignorestderr curl ...`